# How can I use binary search to search for the first item in a List greater than a specific value?

Tags: java, list, search, binary

using Java. the List is sorted so I want to use binary search. I'd prefer not to write extra code, is there any built-in method to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29)? That basically does the search part - you'd then need to look at whether the result was negative (i.e. an exact match wasn't found) and take the bitwise complement if so to find where the item *would* have been inserted.

Comment: what do you mean by "take the bitwise complement"?

Comment: Oh i see it now. I looked at Collections.binarySearch but didn't notice the "insertion point" part. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Oh by the way, I realized if there're multiple items with the same value in the list, then binarySearch would not give the result I wanted when I search for that value. I want the index of the first item equal or greater than a given value actually.

Comment: @Thi: If there can be duplicates, binarySearch will give you *one* of the valid index values... so you'd then want to look backwards until you found and index with a lower value.

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaDocs for [Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) there are around 17 function definitions for binarySearcy()

Also here are a few implementations

EDIT:

Although you said you didn't want to write code, it's a sure fire way to get exactly what you want. And learn along the way :)

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/binary-search-implementation-in-java.html
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Search/Binary_search

Comment: Love the name, had to look up its meaning. ;)

Comment: Well i know you said that you really didn't want to write new code. But given what is available in the api try out some of the code snippets i have added to my post

Comment: We are working on a sorted list, here, so I think it would be more logical to use the Collections framework than the Arrays one.

Comment: +1 I also agree with you that Collecitons would be a good idea. It has in the specification of binarySearch that the list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator. Give your points to @zloster (i haven't had coffee yet)